# FlowDocument Memory Issue in C# (But WinDbg gcroot shows “Found 0 unique roots”

Tags: wpf, memory-leaks, windbg, flowdocument

Hi I created a **window** in wpf.
It is a Print preview screen.
It displays (FixedDocumentSequence) in **DocumentViewer**.
FixedDocumentSequence was created by Flow Document with dynamic binding.

single window occupy nearly 500MB.
Every time memory leaks about 100MB.
If opens more than 5 or 10 times **memory overflow** 1GB.

I opens window in STA thread(not UI thread). Execute Dispatcher shutdown method. But some objects not release from memory.(after dispatcher shutdown memory object still alive?)

I have used WinDbg to check memory leak, the Flow document section still displays.

```
 !dumpheap -stat
```

I check the root of the object. But it shows **“Found 0 unique roots”**

```
 !gcroot [address]
```

My English may be poor to understand the meaning of the question.

**[Question No.1]** Could you please give me any suggestions to solve the memory leaks.

(Another one information and question:

I want try to set null too in dispose method.

GC finalizer call the destructor from another thread.
so run time can’t saw the object value and can’t set the value to null in dispose method.

**[Question No.2]** I already shutdown the dispatcher. So is it necessary to implement anything in Dispose(bool disposing) method?)

Comment: If your object has no root then it's unlikely to be a memory leak. It could just be that the GC hasn't reclaimed the memory yet. Try running `GC.Collect(2)` and see what happens

Comment: GC.Collect(2) helps something better. thank you.
 manually Disposed some objects, then After ShutDown, Thread sleep 1secod, then call GC.Collect(2). Solved 90%.

Answer (score 0):

> Every time memory leaks about 100MB.

Actually that's great. Memory leaks that are reproducible should be easy to fix.

> I opens window in STA thread(not UI thread).

I don't understand. If you use `Application.Run()`, that thread will become a UI thread.

> I check the root of the object.

Which object? And why did you choose it?

> But it shows “Found 0 unique roots”

That means it's eligible for garbage collection. Next time the garbage collector runs, it will likely be gone.

> I want try to set null too in dispose method.

For the object that is reported as "Found 0 unique roots", that has already been done.

But even if you set all variables to `null`, the objects will still be there. You just don't have a reference any more.

> GC finalizer call the destructor from another thread.

That's normal. There is a dedicated finalizer thread.

> so run time can’t saw the object value and can’t set the value to null in dispose method.

You can set variables to `null` inside the finalizer thread. Memory can be accessed from all threads.

> So is it necessary to implement anything in Dispose(bool disposing) method?)

Without knowing what resources your window uses, that's hard to tell.

**How to procede?**

First, get a better tool than WinDbg. It can be done with WinDbg, but it's a lot of effort. No matter what tool you use:

1. Run the leaky application
2. Reproduce the leak
3. Force a garbage collection (implement a button if you can't do otherwise)
4. Take a snapshot (basically that's a full `!dumpheap`)
5. Reproduce the leak again 7 times if possible (otherwise 5 or 3 times)
6. Force a garbage collection again
7. Take a snapshot again
8. Compare the two snapshots (create a diff)

In the snapshot diff, you can now look for new objects that have a multiple of 7 (like 21, 70, 91, ...). These are the ones that leaked. Check the GC roots of those.

It's quite unlikely to leak 5, 6, 8 or 9 objects when you reproduce the leak 7 times. I choose a prime or at least odd number, because multiples of 2, 4 and 8 occur naturally in computer programs.

Doing the diff with the output of `!dumpheap` in WinDbg is hard. You probably need a `.logopen` to capture all output. And maybe you end up writing your own parser for the logfile then.

I see a lot of developers use Jetbrains Resharper. Some licenses include  [dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/). I'm quite happy with it, it gets the job done.

Comment: Thankyou for the wonderful time for solve me. I got encouragement after your reply.
thanks a lot.

>I don't understand. If you use Application.Run(), that thread will become a UI thread.


https://eprystupa.wordpress.com/2008/07/28/running-wpf-application-with-multiple-ui-threads/

GC.Collect(2) helps something better. thank you.

 manually Disposed some objects, then After ShutDown, Thread sleep 1secod, then call GC.Collect(2). Solved 90%.

Comment: Related:
https://turecki.net/flowdocument-from-a-different-thread